# How can change one navigation item to an image in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a site here: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/

And been wondering if I could change the first item "iLiveAccountable" to an  image.

So instead of like this: [image]

It will be like this:

[image]

How can I do it in Wordpress?

Comment: open your header.php file , and add `<img src="your-theme-path/logo.png" />` to your template file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you do not provide a source example, so the explanation is just theoretical.

Expect the list of menu is an `<ul>` Tag. So the first `<li>` item is you want to change.
First select the first item and "hide the text" with:

```
.myULclass li:first-child {
   text-indent: -9999em;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

And add image:

```
.myULclass li:first-child:before {
   content: url(image.jpg);
}
```

That should do the work. Of course you need to add some other properties for image size and so on.

Note, this is a pure CSS solution without changing your template.